# What is the use case for `set_freeze`, `remove_freeze` and `thaw_nft` instructions in CandyMachine

Tags: rust, candy-machine-v2, freeze

I've seen these instructions in the source code, however, I couldn't find any documentation on them. What is the purpose of those 3 instructions and in which situations should I use them?

EDIT:
I've found [this commit](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/pull/669) with the description **what** those instructions do, however, I still do not understand **why** I might want to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the PR you linked explains it: it's a way to freeze NFTs for a certain time immediately after they're minted.

> `set_freeze`: This handler sets the freeze conditions on a Candy Machine. It can only be called prior to any NFTs minting out.

This needs to be on the candy machine program because it's set immediately on mint and needs to be done before any NFTs have been minted.

Some NFT collections distribute 'tickets' on mint that can be exchanged for the actual NFT later. Those 'tickets' come with a 100% royalty to avoid them being traded. The idea seems to be to stop any trading happening before the collection is fully minted. It looks like this might be an alternative to that and achieve a similar outcome.

Comment: The last paragraph was extremely helpful, as it explains why someone might want to freeze them. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The main use case I can think of for the "freeze" utility is for staking. When an NFT is staked with the ability to be frozen, it can not be transferred until it is unstaked.

Comment: Thank you! I know that usually freezing is used for staking. However! Candy Machine is used for buying NFTs, not staking them, so I got a bit confused in this regard.